# Remove h1 from 2015 theme

Tags: theme-development, themes, child-theme

I'm a Wordpress newbie! I have two h1 when I list my site categories using a URL of the following format:

> http://www.example.com/category/YYY

I get a HTML page with a header of

```
Category: <h1>....
```

then another h1 with my post title. How can I remove the first h1?

Things I've tried:

1. I found the offending CSS using Inspect Element. I have created a child theme with the following code:

   ```
   .page-header {
       display: none;
   }
   ```

This removes the extra h1, but the extra h1 tag is still visible when I view the page source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the according *template file* out of the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy), so in your case the template regarding the [Category Display](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Category_display).